# CNN on Audio Data not learning

Tags: audio, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train CNN on audio data for regression. This is my Network Architecture:

```
name: "AudioRegression"
layer{
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "c_trainList.txt"
    batch_size: 32
    shuffle: true
  }
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}
layer{
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "d_testList.txt"
    batch_size: 32
  }
  include: { phase: TEST }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param { lr_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  param { lr_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  param { lr_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_h: 1
    kernel_w: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer{
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "fc1"
  param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0 }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1024
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "dropout1"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "fc1"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer{
  name: "fc2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "fc2"
  param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0 }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
 }
}
layer{
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "fc2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

After running for about 6,000 iterations (my total training data was around 3000 and I tested on same data for checking how well the CNN works) , eventually the prediction looks like this: [Red = Actual Label, Blue = Prediction]

[image: Prediction_Output]

I am not sure why my prediction is so bad. I have checked increasing the amount of data and also number of iteration, but the result is similar. I also checked with spectrograms with no luck. My input audio data length is 1721(1D) (which is approx 40ms, 44.1KHz samp rate).

Can you please suggest what I could do to improve my results? Is there something wrong with the architecture or the way I'm taking in the data? Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Here is my training log:

```
I1209 00:01:47.464259  2189 solver.cpp:47] Solver scaffolding done.
I1209 00:01:47.464296  2189 solver.cpp:363] Solving AudioRegression
I1209 00:01:47.464303  2189 solver.cpp:364] Learning Rate Policy: inv
I1209 00:01:47.499138  2189 solver.cpp:424] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I1209 00:04:07.222735  2189 solver.cpp:481]     Test net output #0: loss = 0.0230729 (* 1 = 0.0230729 loss)
I1209 00:04:10.707535  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 0, loss = 0.0259357
I1209 00:04:10.707590  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0259357 (* 1 = 0.0259357 loss)
I1209 00:04:10.707617  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 0, lr = 0.0001
I1209 00:06:51.835078  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 50, loss = 0.0168364
I1209 00:06:51.835170  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0168364 (* 1 = 0.0168364 loss)
I1209 00:06:51.835182  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 50, lr = 9.96266e-05
I1209 00:09:42.754168  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 100, loss = 0.0115463
I1209 00:09:42.754374  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0115463 (* 1 = 0.0115463 loss)
I1209 00:09:42.754402  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 100, lr = 9.92565e-05
I1209 00:13:08.801769  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 150, loss = 0.0113013
I1209 00:16:21.470883  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0136536 (* 1 = 0.0136536 loss)
I1209 00:16:21.470899  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 200, lr = 9.85258e-05
I1209 00:19:31.274965  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 250, loss = 0.014273
I1209 00:19:31.275111  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.014273 (* 1 = 0.014273 loss)
I1209 00:19:31.275130  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 250, lr = 9.81651e-05
I1209 00:22:41.283741  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 300, loss = 0.016501
I1209 00:22:41.283836  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.016501 (* 1 = 0.016501 loss)
I1209 00:22:41.283850  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 300, lr = 9.78075e-05
I1209 00:25:49.767002  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 350, loss = 0.0229812
I1209 00:25:49.767107  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0229812 (* 1 = 0.0229812 loss)
I1209 00:25:49.767119  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 350, lr = 9.74529e-05
I1209 00:29:11.156260  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 400, loss = 0.0114304
I1209 00:29:11.156347  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0114304 (* 1 = 0.0114304 loss)
I1209 00:29:11.156359  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 400, lr = 9.71013e-05
I1209 00:32:28.614641  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 450, loss = 0.0157431
I1209 00:32:28.614919  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0157431 (* 1 = 0.0157431 loss)
I1209 00:32:28.614943  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 450, lr = 9.67526e-05
I1209 00:35:42.133127  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 500, loss = 0.0166063
I1209 00:35:42.133232  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0166063 (* 1 = 0.0166063 loss)
I1209 00:35:42.133245  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 500, lr = 9.64069e-05
I1209 00:38:54.340562  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 550, loss = 0.0173505
I1209 00:38:54.340664  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0173505 (* 1 = 0.0173505 loss)
I1209 00:48:16.819653  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0121346 (* 1 = 0.0121346 loss)
I1209 00:48:16.819675  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 700, lr = 9.50522e-05
I1209 00:51:06.433248  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 750, loss = 0.0144362
I1209 00:51:06.433331  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0144362 (* 1 = 0.0144362 loss)
I1209 00:51:06.433346  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 750, lr = 9.47204e-05
I1209 00:53:58.998585  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 800, loss = 0.015145
I1209 00:53:58.998919  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.015145 (* 1 = 0.015145 loss)
I1209 00:53:58.998991  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 800, lr = 9.43913e-05
I1209 00:56:48.413203  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 850, loss = 0.00943574
I1209 01:07:50.999053  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1000, lr = 9.31012e-05
I1209 01:10:48.213668  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1050, loss = 0.00977092
I1209 01:10:48.213749  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00977092 (* 1 = 0.00977092 loss)
I1209 01:10:48.213760  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1050, lr = 9.27851e-05
I1209 01:13:38.985514  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1100, loss = 0.0150719
I1209 01:13:38.985610  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0150719 (* 1 = 0.0150719 loss)
I1209 01:13:38.985623  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1100, lr = 9.24715e-05
I1209 01:16:33.194244  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1150, loss = 0.0118601
I1209 01:16:33.194334  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0118601 (* 1 = 0.0118601 loss)
I1209 01:16:33.194345  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1150, lr = 9.21603e-05
I1209 01:19:23.298775  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1200, loss = 0.0122899
I1209 01:19:23.298854  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0122899 (* 1 = 0.0122899 loss)
I1209 01:19:23.298866  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1200, lr = 9.18515e-05
I1209 01:22:15.248015  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1250, loss = 0.00906165
I1209 01:30:49.363504  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.012574 (* 1 = 0.012574 loss)
I1209 01:47:09.507314  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1650, loss = 0.0127013
I1209 01:59:49.763129  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0114391 (* 1 = 0.0114391 loss)
I1209 01:59:49.763147  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1850, lr = 8.80463e-05
I1209 02:03:10.173984  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1900, loss = 0.0138886
I1209 02:03:10.174072  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0138886 (* 1 = 0.0138886 loss)
I1209 02:03:10.174087  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1900, lr = 8.77687e-05
I1209 02:06:20.400573  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 1950, loss = 0.0137628
I1209 02:06:20.400668  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 1950, lr = 8.74932e-05
I1209 02:09:27.890867  2189 solver.cpp:502] Snapshotting to outputModel_iter_2000.caffemodel
I1209 02:09:29.180711  2189 solver.cpp:510] Snapshotting solver state to outputModel_iter_2000.solverstate
I1209 02:09:30.414371  2189 solver.cpp:424] Iteration 2000, Testing net (#0)
I1209 02:12:13.271689  2189 solver.cpp:481]     Test net output #0: loss = 0.01289 (* 1 = 0.01289 loss)
I1209 02:12:16.724727  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2000, loss = 0.0207793
I1209 02:12:16.724778  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0207793 (* 1 = 0.0207793 loss)
I1209 02:12:16.724791  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2000, lr = 8.72196e-05
I1209 02:15:27.976011  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2050, loss = 0.0118718
I1209 02:15:27.976099  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0118718 (* 1 = 0.0118718 loss)
I1209 02:15:27.976111  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2050, lr = 8.6948e-05
I1209 02:18:45.454749  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2100, loss = 0.00938784
I1209 02:18:45.454834  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00938784 (* 1 = 0.00938784 loss)
I1209 02:18:45.454852  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2100, lr = 8.66784e-05
I1209 02:22:03.167448  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2150, loss = 0.0127745
I1209 02:22:03.167531  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0127745 (* 1 = 0.0127745 loss)
I1209 02:22:03.167546  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2150, lr = 8.64107e-05
I1209 02:25:14.789314  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2200, loss = 0.00956969
I1209 02:25:14.789397  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00956969 (* 1 = 0.00956969 loss)
I1209 02:25:14.789410  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2200, lr = 8.6145e-05
I1209 02:28:25.455724  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2250, loss = 0.0143162
I1209 02:28:25.455807  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0143162 (* 1 = 0.0143162 loss)
I1209 02:28:25.455819  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2250, lr = 8.58812e-05
I1209 02:31:35.905241  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2300, loss = 0.00927413
I1209 02:31:35.905323  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00927413 (* 1 = 0.00927413 loss)
I1209 02:31:35.905335  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2300, lr = 8.56192e-05
I1209 02:34:56.982108  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2350, loss = 0.0176598
I1209 02:34:56.982213  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0176598 (* 1 = 0.0176598 loss)
I1209 02:34:56.982231  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2350, lr = 8.53591e-05
I1209 02:38:06.427983  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2400, loss = 0.0125867
I1209 02:38:06.428068  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0125867 (* 1 = 0.0125867 loss)
I1209 02:38:06.428081  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2400, lr = 8.51008e-05
I1209 02:41:16.814347  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2450, loss = 0.01254
I1209 02:41:16.814467  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.01254 (* 1 = 0.01254 loss)
I1209 02:41:16.814481  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2450, lr = 8.48444e-05
I1209 02:44:24.596612  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2500, loss = 0.0128213
I1209 02:44:24.596699  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0128213 (* 1 = 0.0128213 loss)
I1209 02:44:24.596711  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2500, lr = 8.45897e-05
I1209 02:47:41.383929  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2550, loss = 0.0138613
I1209 02:47:41.384017  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0138613 (* 1 = 0.0138613 loss)
I1209 02:47:41.384029  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2550, lr = 8.43368e-05
I1209 02:51:01.780666  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2600, loss = 0.0135385
I1209 02:51:01.780769  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0135385 (* 1 = 0.0135385 loss)
I1209 02:51:01.780786  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2600, lr = 8.40857e-05
I1209 02:54:09.573009  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2650, loss = 0.0128414
I1209 02:54:09.573094  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0128414 (* 1 = 0.0128414 loss)
I1209 02:54:09.573107  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2650, lr = 8.38363e-05
I1209 02:57:19.939091  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2700, loss = 0.0132472
I1209 02:57:19.939178  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0132472 (* 1 = 0.0132472 loss)
I1209 02:57:19.939191  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2700, lr = 8.35886e-05
I1209 03:00:40.396674  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2750, loss = 0.0121989
I1209 03:00:40.396757  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0121989 (* 1 = 0.0121989 loss)
I1209 03:00:40.396770  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2750, lr = 8.33427e-05
I1209 03:03:49.423348  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2800, loss = 0.0132731
I1209 03:03:49.423435  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0132731 (* 1 = 0.0132731 loss)
I1209 03:03:49.423449  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2800, lr = 8.30984e-05
I1209 03:06:59.472712  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2850, loss = 0.00996264
I1209 03:06:59.472822  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00996264 (* 1 = 0.00996264 loss)
I1209 03:06:59.472837  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2850, lr = 8.28558e-05
I1209 03:10:11.587728  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2900, loss = 0.00787597
I1209 03:10:11.587813  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00787597 (* 1 = 0.00787597 loss)
I1209 03:10:11.587826  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2900, lr = 8.26148e-05
I1209 03:13:26.526146  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 2950, loss = 0.0113055
I1209 03:13:26.526232  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0113055 (* 1 = 0.0113055 loss)
I1209 03:13:26.526244  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 2950, lr = 8.23754e-05
I1209 03:16:33.236115  2189 solver.cpp:424] Iteration 3000, Testing net (#0)
I1209 03:19:24.886912  2189 solver.cpp:481]     Test net output #0: loss = 0.0127196 (* 1 = 0.0127196 loss)
I1209 03:19:28.444213  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3000, loss = 0.0217011
I1209 03:26:00.578351  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3100, lr = 8.1667e-05
I1209 03:29:11.128749  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3150, loss = 0.0186126
I1209 03:29:11.128832  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0186126 (* 1 = 0.0186126 loss)
I1209 03:29:11.128844  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3150, lr = 8.1434e-05
I1209 03:32:21.431370  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3200, loss = 0.013207
I1209 03:32:21.431488  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.013207 (* 1 = 0.013207 loss)
I1209 03:38:42.957159  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3300, loss = 0.0143691
I1209 03:38:42.957262  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0143691 (* 1 = 0.0143691 loss)
I1209 03:38:42.957275  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3300, lr = 8.07442e-05
I1209 03:41:56.213155  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3350, loss = 0.0111833
I1209 03:41:56.213243  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0111833 (* 1 = 0.0111833 loss)
I1209 03:41:56.213255  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3350, lr = 8.05173e-05
I1209 03:45:03.395630  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3400, loss = 0.0128313
I1209 03:45:03.396034  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0128313 (* 1 = 0.0128313 loss)
I1209 03:45:03.396091  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3400, lr = 8.02918e-05
I1209 03:48:14.938372  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3450, loss = 0.0114032
I1209 03:48:14.938454  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0114032 (* 1 = 0.0114032 loss)
I1209 03:48:14.938467  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3450, lr = 8.00679e-05
I1209 03:51:24.561987  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3500, loss = 0.0146534
I1209 03:51:24.562098  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0146534 (* 1 = 0.0146534 loss)
I1209 03:51:24.562114  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3500, lr = 7.98454e-05
I1209 03:54:35.916950  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3550, loss = 0.0107792
I1209 03:54:35.917058  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0107792 (* 1 = 0.0107792 loss)
I1209 03:54:35.917073  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3550, lr = 7.96243e-05
I1209 03:57:44.691856  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3600, loss = 0.0131089
I1209 03:57:44.691939  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0131089 (* 1 = 0.0131089 loss)
I1209 03:57:44.691951  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3600, lr = 7.94046e-05
I1209 04:00:50.050279  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3650, loss = 0.00767588
I1209 04:00:50.050366  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00767588 (* 1 = 0.00767588 loss)
I1209 04:00:50.050379  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3650, lr = 7.91864e-05
I1209 04:03:36.047211  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3700, loss = 0.0110371
I1209 04:03:36.047299  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0110371 (* 1 = 0.0110371 loss)
I1209 04:03:36.047312  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3700, lr = 7.89695e-05
I1209 04:06:27.261343  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3750, loss = 0.0176664
I1209 04:06:27.261425  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0176664 (* 1 = 0.0176664 loss)
I1209 04:06:27.261438  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3750, lr = 7.87541e-05
I1209 04:09:20.277091  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3800, loss = 0.0133606
I1209 04:09:20.277186  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0133606 (* 1 = 0.0133606 loss)
I1209 04:09:20.277199  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3800, lr = 7.854e-05
I1209 04:12:11.541723  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3850, loss = 0.0144475
I1209 04:12:11.541936  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0144475 (* 1 = 0.0144475 loss)
I1209 04:12:11.541952  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3850, lr = 7.83272e-05
I1209 04:15:03.661646  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3900, loss = 0.0142342
I1209 04:15:03.661834  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0142342 (* 1 = 0.0142342 loss)
I1209 04:15:03.661852  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3900, lr = 7.81158e-05
I1209 04:17:53.149144  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 3950, loss = 0.0121178
I1209 04:17:53.149250  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0121178 (* 1 = 0.0121178 loss)
I1209 04:17:53.149263  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 3950, lr = 7.79057e-05
I1209 04:20:40.580508  2189 solver.cpp:502] Snapshotting to outputModel_iter_4000.caffemodel
I1209 04:20:41.779126  2189 solver.cpp:510] Snapshotting solver state to outputModel_iter_4000.solverstate
I1209 04:20:42.885267  2189 solver.cpp:424] Iteration 4000, Testing net (#0)
I1209 04:23:32.727929  2189 solver.cpp:481]     Test net output #0: loss = 0.0126429 (* 1 = 0.0126429 loss)
I1209 04:23:36.443990  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4000, loss = 0.0137481
I1209 04:23:36.444049  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0137481 (* 1 = 0.0137481 loss)
I1209 04:23:36.444067  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4000, lr = 7.76969e-05
I1209 04:26:47.281289  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4050, loss = 0.0153349
I1209 04:26:47.281397  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0153349 (* 1 = 0.0153349 loss)
I1209 04:26:47.281410  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4050, lr = 7.74895e-05
I1209 04:30:02.951990  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4100, loss = 0.0117784
I1209 04:30:02.952076  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0117784 (* 1 = 0.0117784 loss)
I1209 04:30:02.952090  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4100, lr = 7.72833e-05
I1209 04:33:12.287106  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4150, loss = 0.0150684
I1209 04:33:12.287194  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0150684 (* 1 = 0.0150684 loss)
I1209 04:33:12.287207  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4150, lr = 7.70784e-05
I1209 04:36:25.405246  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4200, loss = 0.0121092
I1209 05:08:37.213099  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4700, loss = 0.00963576
I1209 05:08:37.213321  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00963576 (* 1 = 0.00963576 loss)
I1209 05:08:37.213338  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4700, lr = 7.49052e-05
I1209 05:11:51.183197  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4750, loss = 0.0177338
I1209 05:11:51.183284  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0177338 (* 1 = 0.0177338 loss)
I1209 05:11:51.183296  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4750, lr = 7.47147e-05
I1209 05:15:12.716320  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4800, loss = 0.0155627
I1209 05:15:12.716401  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0155627 (* 1 = 0.0155627 loss)
I1209 05:15:12.716413  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4800, lr = 7.45253e-05
I1209 05:18:36.245213  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4850, loss = 0.0110798
I1209 05:18:36.245301  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0110798 (* 1 = 0.0110798 loss)
I1209 05:18:36.245314  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4850, lr = 7.4337e-05
I1209 05:21:53.006510  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4900, loss = 0.0149542
I1209 05:21:53.006613  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0149542 (* 1 = 0.0149542 loss)
I1209 05:21:53.006630  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4900, lr = 7.41499e-05
I1209 05:25:05.802839  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 4950, loss = 0.0152574
I1209 05:25:05.802940  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0152574 (* 1 = 0.0152574 loss)
I1209 05:25:05.802953  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 4950, lr = 7.39638e-05
I1209 05:28:12.186930  2189 solver.cpp:424] Iteration 5000, Testing net (#0)
I1209 05:30:57.153729  2189 solver.cpp:481]     Test net output #0: loss = 0.0127499 (* 1 = 0.0127499 loss)
I1209 05:31:00.795545  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5000, loss = 0.0118315
I1209 05:31:00.795598  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0118315 (* 1 = 0.0118315 loss)
I1209 05:31:00.795609  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5000, lr = 7.37788e-05
I1209 05:34:18.038789  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5050, loss = 0.0147696
I1209 05:34:18.038875  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0147696 (* 1 = 0.0147696 loss)
I1209 05:34:18.038887  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5050, lr = 7.35949e-05
I1209 05:37:39.033630  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5100, loss = 0.0114872
I1209 05:37:39.033713  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0114872 (* 1 = 0.0114872 loss)
I1209 05:37:39.033725  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5100, lr = 7.3412e-05
I1209 05:40:54.287984  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5150, loss = 0.0112272
I1209 05:40:54.288146  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0112272 (* 1 = 0.0112272 loss)
I1209 05:40:54.288163  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5150, lr = 7.32303e-05
I1209 05:44:05.552100  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5200, loss = 0.0123504
I1209 05:44:05.552181  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0123504 (* 1 = 0.0123504 loss)
I1209 05:44:05.552193  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5200, lr = 7.30495e-05
I1209 05:47:18.410975  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5250, loss = 0.0172216
I1209 05:47:18.411062  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0172216 (* 1 = 0.0172216 loss)
I1209 05:47:18.411074  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5250, lr = 7.28698e-05
I1209 05:50:33.027614  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5300, loss = 0.0126125
I1209 05:50:33.027719  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0126125 (* 1 = 0.0126125 loss)
I1209 05:50:33.027731  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5300, lr = 7.26911e-05
I1209 05:53:44.704063  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5350, loss = 0.0117126
I1209 05:53:44.704151  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0117126 (* 1 = 0.0117126 loss)
I1209 05:53:44.704164  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5350, lr = 7.25135e-05
I1209 05:56:53.016206  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5400, loss = 0.00555667
I1209 05:56:53.016294  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00555667 (* 1 = 0.00555667 loss)
I1209 05:56:53.016306  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5400, lr = 7.23368e-05
I1209 06:00:04.420944  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5450, loss = 0.0111433
I1209 06:00:04.421066  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0111433 (* 1 = 0.0111433 loss)
I1209 06:00:04.421078  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5450, lr = 7.21612e-05
I1209 06:03:28.763087  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5500, loss = 0.00962537
I1209 06:03:28.763197  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00962537 (* 1 = 0.00962537 loss)
I1209 06:03:28.763214  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5500, lr = 7.19865e-05
I1209 06:06:39.725003  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5550, loss = 0.0111173
I1209 06:06:39.725289  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0111173 (* 1 = 0.0111173 loss)
I1209 06:06:39.725307  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5550, lr = 7.18129e-05
I1209 06:09:52.560111  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5600, loss = 0.0151178
I1209 06:09:52.560214  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0151178 (* 1 = 0.0151178 loss)
I1209 06:09:52.560227  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5600, lr = 7.16402e-05
I1209 06:13:05.462718  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5650, loss = 0.0125453
I1209 06:13:05.462803  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0125453 (* 1 = 0.0125453 loss)
I1209 06:13:05.462815  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5650, lr = 7.14684e-05
I1209 06:16:16.187785  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5700, loss = 0.00663404
I1209 06:16:16.187870  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00663404 (* 1 = 0.00663404 loss)
I1209 06:16:16.187880  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5700, lr = 7.12977e-05
I1209 06:19:29.129866  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5750, loss = 0.0136638
I1209 06:19:29.129968  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0136638 (* 1 = 0.0136638 loss)
I1209 06:19:29.129981  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5750, lr = 7.11278e-05
I1209 06:22:42.243834  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5800, loss = 0.0119521
I1209 06:29:11.570849  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0123193 (* 1 = 0.0123193 loss)
I1209 06:29:11.570874  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5900, lr = 7.0624e-05
I1209 06:32:26.092237  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 5950, loss = 0.0102198
I1209 06:32:26.092344  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0102198 (* 1 = 0.0102198 loss)
I1209 06:32:26.092360  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 5950, lr = 7.04579e-05
I1209 06:35:40.060386  2189 solver.cpp:502] Snapshotting to outputModel_iter_6000.caffemodel
I1209 06:35:41.191196  2189 solver.cpp:510] Snapshotting solver state to outputModel_iter_6000.solverstate
I1209 06:35:42.254009  2189 solver.cpp:424] Iteration 6000, Testing net (#0)
I1209 06:38:31.810992  2189 solver.cpp:481]     Test net output #0: loss = 0.0125662 (* 1 = 0.0125662 loss)
I1209 06:38:35.926373  2189 solver.cpp:240] Iteration 6000, loss = 0.0130608
I1209 06:38:35.926427  2189 solver.cpp:255]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0130608 (* 1 = 0.0130608 loss)
I1209 06:38:35.926440  2189 solver.cpp:631] Iteration 6000, lr = 7.02927e-05
```

Comment: 40 ms is too short for emotion estimation, even a human cannot do that. What you need (at minimum) is to have an analysis window which is on the order of 1 second long. This will then be composed of many time-frames, say 40x 25ms = 1 second. Converting to a spectrogram representation is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any appreciable reduction in your loss which means your network is not really learning. As you are testing on the training data itself and still getting low accuracy, it implies your network is underfitting. There are a couple of things I can suggest, though. First, try running for more number of iterations and see if the loss decreases. And second, you may experiment with your learning rate as well. Try keeping it higher in the beginning.

Comment: I have tested the network on more data and more iteration too, which resulted in similar (bad) prediction. I have gone up to 90 thousand iterations with about 30 thousand data.

Comment: As a golden rule of debugging - do not make more than one change at a time. First take the smaller dataset and run for higher number of iterations before you go for larger dataset.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that, the results posted above are for smaller(3000) dataset. I am not sure where the problem is, the data I'm taking or the network. I don't know how could the data be wrong as it's just data. and about the network architecture, I've tested the same architecture with different dimension(2D for Image), it worked fine. Now when I'm checking it for 1D data(after making some dimensional changes like kernel size) it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Too less information to answer your question. How much data you have? What is the task, actually? What do you predict from audio?

It can be any of dozens of reasons, why everything is going wrong. But there are two things, that look strange. First, you use raw audio data, while I would strongly recommend using spectral features. Second, this part in your network definition looks suspicious:

```
top: "fc2"
  param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0 }
  inner_product_param {
```

I usually use named parameters:

```
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    name: "conv2_w"
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    name: "conv2_b"
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
```

But even if you do everything correctly with net definition and data preparation, it does not mean that you chose correct method to solve your task and that your task makes sense at all.

Comment: I am trying to do emotional prediction, I have plenty of data. But as I stated in the original question, I have tested the network on more data and more iteration too, which resulted in similar (bad) prediction. What I have understood up to now is that 40ms audio data (at 44.1KHz rate) should be enough to do the (emotional) prediction. and also I have a question, as the network itself is extracting some sort of features for prediction, so shouldn't the raw data be more advantageous than the spectral features? Because raw data contains more information than any of the feature extracted from it.

Comment: What is emotional prediction? What value do you predict? Valence, arousal, level of anger? 

"shouldn't the raw data be more advantageous than the spectral features?" - Short answer is no. Moreover, since you deal with recognition of emotions I encourage you to use dedicated features for this (related to pitch, energy and spectrum). See openSMILE toolkit. 

Also, 40ms is not enough, I believe.

Comment: Right now I'm trying for valence. I tried ConvNet in the first place because I thought it will automatically cut the unnecessary aspects of data and extract its own features. I'll try with features and see what happens then. And also can you suggest me what can be the appropriate data duration, if not 40ms? It'll be really helpful. As per my intuition 40ms indeed feels less to capture an emotion but as far as I have read, people have extracted features even from 25ms. I'm very confused.

Comment: 25ms is the frame duration, but from each audio sample numerous frames are extracted. Valence is very difficult to classify correctly (even for humans), it is even more difficult to predict it's nominal value. But if you do want to continue in that direction, I would suggest reading some literature first (e.g. Deep neural networks for acoustic emotion recognition: raising the benchmarks) and trying to reproduce methods described there. NNs are not magic black boxes, to process speech we still need sort of feature extraction.